# View with 'filters and row_num function' causing over utilization of resources and performance degradation

Tags: performance, hadoop, optimization, hive, bigdata

We have a partitioned table of 50+ columns and 30+ million records. The task is to filter 200 latest records out of it based on the conditions matching on 3 columns. We have created a view and applied row_number function PARTITION BY those 3 columns ORDER BY load_date. Now while querying this, it is causing performance degradation and over-utilization of resources. >Is there anything that I can try from query optimization end to improve the performance?

**QUERY:**

```
SELECT * FROM view_name
WHERE data_as_of_date=20191213 and rule_row_num<=200
and rule_id='some_id' and run_id='some_run_id';
```

**VIEW CREATION:**

```
CREATE VIEW view_name as SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY data_as_of_date, rule_id, run_id ORDER BY load_date DESC) as rule_row_num from table_name;
```

Comment: a) You can collect statistics on the columns if you haven't done so already. b) Can you show your `explain` output?

Comment: @mazaneicha On trying the describe formatted over the partition column, I am getting the below response: "Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Error in getting fields from serde.Invalid Field". However, this is the same over other partitioned tables and similar applications are working without any error over those.